# Why my linux machine is running slow?

Tags: ubuntu

Hello I am using Lubuntu 20.04

```
abhishek@abhishek:~$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               abhishek@abhishek 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ----------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Kernel: 5.4.0-72-generic 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Uptime: 44 mins 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Packages: 2250 (dpkg) 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Shell: bash 5.0.17 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Resolution: 1280x1024 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   DE: LXQt 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Openbox 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM Theme: Lubuntu Arc 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Theme: Arc-Darker [GTK2/3] 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Icons: ePapirus [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Terminal: qterminal 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal Font: Ubuntu Mono 14 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo E7200 (2) @ 2.526GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: Intel 82945G/GZ 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 2045MiB / 2983MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.                                       
                                                                   


abhishek@abhishek:~$
```

My machine nowadays lags to such an extent, that it seems unusable. For example, previously, when I had freshly installed my Lubuntu 20.04 around 1.5 years (or before that, I used an older version of Lubuntu: 18.10), there were no such freezing or late response issues.

But lately, I am experiencing great trouble. Switching from one tab to another in firefox takes 2-3 minutes sometimes, and that time, the HDD makes a peculiar mouse-like squeaking sound.

I have a ram of 3 GB and a swap space of 4 GB. Why has the performance of my system degraded? How to rectify it?

[image: iotop]

*iotop output*

Comment: Have you tried to restart(power off and power on) your computer?

Comment: @FairOPShotgun that is unlikely to help in any case, but the OP's output shows an uptime of 44 minutes, so the system was restarted less than an hour ago.

Comment: @terdon What about transferring all of the files onto a USB and rebooting the computer?

Comment: Sound from the hard drive is a very bad sign. How old is the machine? Based on your CPU, I am guessing it is many years old. Have you [checked the S.M.A.R.T status](https://www.aptgetlife.co.uk/checking-a-hard-drives-smart-status-from-the-command-line/) of your drive?

Comment: @FairOPShotgun um, why would that make any difference? What files? Why would files be relevant?

Comment: Yeah, noises from the hard drive are not good.  Does your laptop use a standard sata interface?  if so, it might be time to replace the drive with a 2.5" sata ssd.  This would also give a nice performance boost too (booting, loading programs, reading files, and swap will all benefit).   And if your laptop is capable of taking more RAM (or swapping a 1 or 2GB SODIMM for a 2 or 4GB SODIMM), that would be a good idea too....software improvements (and bloat) continues apace and what was adequate several years ago may no longer be enough.

Comment: If you can't replace the drive, it would be a very good idea to get an external USB drive so that you can make regular backups.

Comment: @terdon the disk is around 8 year old. I have checked the S.M.A.R.T. status of the disk, it says a property failed in past and also says about few bad sectors. But it also says the disk is O.K. I have switched off my pc now. I shall share the screenshot of the same next time I switch it on. But one thing is that the windows partion runs smoothly(but I rarely use that partition).

Comment: Just be aware that SMART can't detect everything. If the disk is physically failing, then there could be a problem it can't detect.  Eg squeaky bearings are usually worn out bearings.  If they fail completely then it could be in the order of $1,000 dollars to get a data recovery firm to recover your files.

Comment: Bad disk would be my guess.  One give-away is a super high %usage and a very low throughput.  Your journaling process is running at 99% and IO is only 2MB/sec.  Given the low amount of memory, there's a good bet that firefox and other GUI processes are swapping... this will be painfully slow on a failing disk.  Grab Clonezilla (or something similar) and copy the disk contents to a new drive... SSD if you can get one.  If you want more detailed data, provide output from top, iostat and vmstat.

Comment: +1 for using neofetch.